# Type which intersects with other Type equals never

Tags: typescript

```
type TestC = "c" 
type TestABC = ("a" | "b") & TestC; // vscode says type TestABC = never
```

I expected type TestABC should be TestABC = "a" | "b" | "c", but never

I have no idea why TsetABC = never.

Any ideas?

Comment: `type TestABC = "a" | "b" | TestC;`

Comment: @hoangdv Great! it works perfectly!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intersection of two primitive types that the compiler knows can't be instantiated with any concrete value will be simplified to `never`. So for example `string & number` is simplified to `never`, since no value can be both a number and a string AT THE SAME TIME.

In your case you intersect the union `"a" | "b"` with the string literal type `"c"`. Means that a value belonging in this type can be either `"a"` or `"b"` but AT THE SAME TIME  must be `"c"` which is obviously impossible.

As pointed out in the comments you probably want `"a" | "b" | TestC` which is `"a" | "b" | "c"` which means a value can belonging n this type can be either `"a"` or `"b"` or `"c"`